# QApplication::saveState and QApplication::commitData on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

When are the virtual functions `QApplication::saveState` and `QApplication::commitData` called on *Windows*?
Are they called at all, or is session management just a UNIX thing?
Are they called if the app is running when the user logs out (and the app is forcibly shut down)?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/session.html

Comment: You have to override the methods and implement how you want your application to save it's edited docs and/or state as well as how you want it to restore them. They are providing a framework not a solution. If you show us what you've coded so far we probably could give you some suggestions.

Comment: I certainly do understand that in order to make the functions do anything useful I have to override them in a class that I derive from QApplication. But that was not my question. My question is "When are the virtual functions QApplication::saveState and QApplication::commitData called on Windows?" and more specifically "Are they called at all, or is session management just a UNIX thing?" and "Are they called if the app is running when the user logs out (and the app is forcibly shut down)?"

Comment: Windows usually only supports the `commitData` on exit prompting the user to save changes. If you crash or task kill the application all bets are off unless you periodically are saving state similar to what MS Office does. MFC style programs like Office typically save their state to the registry you can do this with the `QSettings` object. `commitData` is called when the application receives the close event which on windows is `WM_CLOSE` for the main window. Are you sure you read the documentation because I'm paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> #### Getting Session Management to Work with Qt
>
> Start by reimplementing QApplication::commitData() to enable your application to take part in the graceful logout process. If you are only targeting the Microsoft Windows platform, this is *all* you **can** and *must* provide. (emphasis added)

[commitData() is called](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/kernel/qapplication_win.cpp#line1511) when a windows application receives the [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) windows message.

From the WM_QUERYENDSESSION docs:

> The WM_QUERYENDSESSION message is sent when the user chooses to end the session or when an application calls one of the system shutdown functions. If any application returns zero, the session is not ended. The system stops sending WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages as soon as one application returns zero.
>
> After processing this message, the system sends the WM_ENDSESSION message with the wParam parameter set to the results of the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qapplication.html#commitData

Comment: In many cases there is no need to reimplement QApplication::commitData(). The default implementation sends close events to all top-level windows. For most applications, this will trigger a normal shut-down. Many applications save their state during a normal shut-down. If that is the case, the default implementation is all you need.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple test app; see below. I compiled the app with Qt 4.7 and MSVS 2010 and ran it on Windows XP. Then I ran three different tests:

1. Start the app. Terminate the app using the close button in the main window.
2. Start the app. Terminate the app using *End Task* in the Task Manager.
3. Start the app. Log out with the app running.

Result of the tests:

- QApplication::commitData is called only in case 3
- QApplication::saveState is not called in any of the three cases.

Here is the code for the test app. The commitData and saveState functions don't do anything useful; the only purpose of the app is to check whether they are called or not.

```
#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QtGui/QtGui>
#include <fstream>

class MyApplication : public QApplication {
public:
    MyApplication(int& argc, char** argv) : QApplication(argc, argv) {}

    virtual void saveState(QSessionManager& manager)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("SaveState.txt");
        ofs << "Test";
    }

    virtual void commitData(QSessionManager& manager)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("CommitData.txt");
        ofs << "Test";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("Begin.txt");
        ofs << "Test";
    }

    MyApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mw;
    mw.show();
    app.exec();

    {
         std::ofstream ofs("End.txt");
         ofs << "Test";
    }
}
```